# add a bilingual caption for table on page two

Tags: longtable, bicaption

I'm trying to use bicaption for longtable, but I have a problem:

I want to add a bilingual caption for table on page two, but I only can add an English caption or the other language caption. What can I do to achieve it?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[UTF-8]{ctexbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for random text
\usepackage{longtable} % for long table
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{bicaption}
\DeclareCaptionOption{bi-first}[]{
    \def\tablename{表}
    \def\figurename{图}}
\DeclareCaptionOption{bi-second}[]{
    \def\tablename{Table.}
    \def\figurename{Fig.}}
\captionsetup[bi-first]{bi-first}
\captionsetup[bi-second]{bi-second}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
\lipsum[1]

{
    \small
    \begin{longtable}{p{4cm}<{\centering} p{4cm}<{\centering} p{4cm}<{\centering}}
        \bicaption{表}{table}
        \label{table:cabin_setup}\\
        \toprule[1.5pt]
        column1 & column2 & column3 \\
        \midrule[0.5pt]
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{3}{c}%
        {\tablename\ \thetable{} table(continued)}\\
        \toprule[1.5pt]
        column1 & column2 & column3\\
        \midrule[0.5pt]
        \endhead
        \bottomrule[1.5pt] \\
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]
        \endlastfoot
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\ \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't process your MWE as I do not have some of the fonts.

Comment: Hi, Peter. I run it successfully on my computer, maybe you can try to compile tex file with xelatex or substitute the Chinese characters for English words. If there are still errors,  I don't know how to do anything to fix it. I'm sorry for it.

Comment: I did compile successfully using xelatex so I could see what the problem was. However, I'm sorry that I can't be of any help.

Comment: I found a manual way to get what I want, maybe it's not perfect. You may glance over my answer for more details. Thank you, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manfully adding that, if you wanna a same format of heading on each later pages, you can just put another `\bicaption` command after the `\endfirsthead`. I put the square brackets before each argument and leave them empty like this: `\bicaption[]{表（续）}[]{table(continued)}` in order to make the caption numbered but not add to the list of tables every time. I made the table longer to show effect and include a list of table on the first page. I don't know if this is better than your method. You can decide which style is you wanted. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[UTF-8]{ctexbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for random text
\usepackage{longtable} % for long table
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{bicaption}

\DeclareCaptionOption{bi-first}[]{
    \def\tablename{表}
    \def\figurename{图}}
\DeclareCaptionOption{bi-second}[]{
    \def\tablename{Table.}
    \def\figurename{Fig.}}
\captionsetup[bi-first]{bi-first}
\captionsetup[bi-second]{bi-second}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\clearpage
\lipsum[1]

{
    \small
    \begin{longtable}{p{4cm}<{\centering} p{4cm}<{\centering} p{4cm}<{\centering}}
        \bicaption{表}{table}
        \label{table:cabin_setup}\\
        \toprule[1.5pt]
        column1 & column2 & column3 \\
        \midrule[0.5pt]
        \endfirsthead
        \bicaption[]{表（续）}[]{table(continued)}\\
        \toprule[1.5pt]
        column1 & column2 & column3\\
        \midrule[0.5pt]
        \endhead
        \bottomrule[1.5pt] \\
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]
        \endlastfoot
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\ \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your method is great and easy to use！I've adopted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I try to add the caption manually and get what I want, although maybe it's not perfect. The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[UTF-8]{ctexbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for random text
\usepackage{longtable} % for long table
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{bicaption}
\DeclareCaptionOption{bi-first}[]{
    \def\tablename{表}
    \def\figurename{图}}
\DeclareCaptionOption{bi-second}[]{
    \def\tablename{Table.}
    \def\figurename{Fig.}}
\captionsetup[bi-first]{bi-first}
\captionsetup[bi-second]{bi-second}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1]
    
    {
        \small
        \begin{longtable}{p{4cm}<{\centering} p{4cm}<{\centering} p{4cm}<{\centering}}
            \bicaption{表}{table}
            \label{table:cabin_setup}\\
            \toprule[1.5pt]
            column1 & column2 & column3 \\
            \midrule[0.5pt]
            \endfirsthead
            \multicolumn{3}{c}%
            {\tablename\ \thetable{} 表(续)}\\
            \multicolumn{3}{c}%
            {\tablename\ \thetable{} table(continued)}\\
            \toprule[1.5pt]
            column1 & column2 & column3\\
            \midrule[0.5pt]
            \endhead
            \bottomrule[1.5pt] \\
            \endfoot
            \bottomrule[1.5pt]
            \endlastfoot
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\ \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \end{longtable}
    }
\end{document}
```